# Displaying props in a second target box

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm *very* new to `react-native`. I'm currently experimenting with it to figure out how I can use it in different ways. Presently, I'm trying to call props of a specifically tapped object and send them to an output box.

So when you tap 'Alan' or 'Steve' their name will appear in the red box.

I'd also like for the dark blue backkground to change to dark red once it's tapped?

I have had a good read of the docs, but I reckon I'm not getting it because it's new to me. I know that I don't seem to be able to access the props of `Component` which is obviously the class `Obj` extends

Guidance greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import style from './style';

class Obj extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity 
      onPressIn={() => this.setState({tapped: true, tappedName: this.props.plrName})}
      onPressOut={() => this.setState({tapped: false, tappedName: null})}>
        <View style={[style.playerobject, style.shadow]}>
          <Text style={[style.plrobjText]}>{this.props.plrName}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      tapped: false,
      tappedName: null,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={[style.main]}>
        <View style={[style.container, this.state.tapped ? {backgroundColor:'darkred'} : {backgroundColor:'darkblue'} ]}>
          <Obj plrName='Alan' />
          <Obj plrName='Steve' />
        </View>
        <View style={style.box }><Text>|{this.state.tapped ? this.state.tappedName : 'x'}|</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: 'Alan' is currently tapped in this screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import style from './style';

class Obj extends Component {

  onPressIn = () => {
    this.props.onPressIn(this.props.plrName)
  }

  onPressOut = () => {
    this.props.onPressOut()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPressIn={this.onPressIn}
        onPressOut={this.onPressOut}>
        <View style={[style.playerobject, style.shadow]}>
          <Text style={[style.plrobjText]}>{this.props.plrName}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tapped: false,
      tappedName: null,
    };
  }

  onPressIn = (tappedName) => {
    this.setState({ tapped: true, tappedName })
  }

  onPressOut = () => {
    this.setState({ tapped: false, tappedName: null })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[style.main]}>
        <View style={[style.container, this.state.tapped ? { backgroundColor: 'darkred' } : { backgroundColor: 'darkblue' }]}>
          <Obj plrName='Alan' onPressIn={this.onPressIn} onPressOut={this.onPressOut} />
          <Obj plrName='Steve' onPressIn={this.onPressIn} onPressOut={this.onPressOut} />
        </View>
        <View style={style.box}><Text>|{this.state.tapped ? this.state.tappedName : 'x'}|</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've read through it and understand how it works with the exception of one part of it. When using `this.props.method()...` within an `extends` class  like you have here, does `this.props.method()` call the method from the parent class or is looking up a level because it can't find something at the local level?

Comment: It calls the function passed as prop from the parent component, in this case `<Obj plrName='Alan' onPressIn={this.onPressIn} />`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Alexander, that make much more sense now. So everything added to an object as `props` in the default class are sent through to the `child/extends` class.

Comment: Yep, you got it :)